# How does django-tasks compare to celery?

Tags: django

I need to batch process records kept inside a database. 
New records are generated on the fly in realtime.

I've briefly looked at celery and stumbled on [django-tasks](http://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/)
Celery requires additional software. Not so with django-tasks.
Has anyone had experience with django-tasks & its performance and reliability ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It depends on what you want to achieve.**

If you want to achieve good performance with a lot of small tasks running in background: **Use celery.**

On the other hand, if you want achieve good performance for a few, "heavy" tasks: **Use django-tasks.**

### Interesting facts

*Celery* has a huge community.

*Django-tasks*'s community is relatively small.

This means you will probably get more support with Celery, when you encounter problems.